# How do you boot Ubuntu Server to RAM?

Tags: boot, boot-to-ram

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 Server on a USB drive, which is the hard drive for this PC. How do I get the bootloader to load Ubuntu onto RAM?

Essentially, this is going to resemble a live-cd type of environment, where the OS is on the CD/USB/HDD (whatever it may be), and gets loaded into RAM.

How do I do this with Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Do you mean to install it on your internal hard disk rather than your USB device?

Comment: No. The USB device is the hard disk for this computer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootToRAM) from the Ubuntu wiki.

Comment: The answer you link to is very old, I'm not sure if it applies anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install the OS on RAM, because it is volatile memory. In other words. as soon as you power off your system, the RAM content is lost. You must install within non-volatile memory such as your HDD or your USB device.

When you boot from non-volatile storage, a boot loader will load your OS from your storage and into RAM.

Hope this helps clarify!

Comment: Edited question to resemble what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instruct/set the BIOS to boot from the USB. At the system splash screen (on start up) press the key that is indicated to enter BIOS Setup (in my system it's F8). Once inside BIOS go to boot device priority and set the USB as first priority. Save and exit.